# MATCH AGAINST not retuning value when match should be found

Tags: mysql, database, match

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Item` WHERE MATCH(`Name`) against('Bakar');
```

But it always returns 0 found when I know I have the value in that column, and it should return with that single row. it works with other values that are in more than one row just not single values. From what I've looked up this should work if a single row or more returns true. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Whats the datatype of the name column

Comment: @Matt it is text